# Outlook.com adds extra characters in plain text emails eg =OA= for a new line

Tags: outlook.com

When I send a plain text message using Outlook.com (my Hotmail recently got upgraded to Outlook automatically), where the body is:

```
subscribe mailinglist-users myemail@hotmail.com
```

the actual message sent is:

```
subscribe mailinglist-users myemail@hotmail.com =
```

Note the "=" at the end of the message.
I then get an automated message from the mailing list system that it doesn't recognise the format of my email:

```
>>>> subscribe mailinglist-users myemail@hotmail.com =
**** The address you supplied, myemail@hotmail.com =
**** does not seem to be a legal Internet address. You may have supplied
**** your full name instead of your address, or you may have included your
**** name along with your address in a manner that does not comply with
**** Internet standards for addresses.
**** It is also possible that you are using a mailer that wraps long lines
**** and the end of your request ended up on the following line. If the
**** latter is true, try using backslashes to split long lines. (Split the
**** line between words, then put a backslash at the end of all but the
**** last line.)

**** subscribe: invalid address 'myemail@hotmail.com ='
```

My question is, how do I stop these extra control characters from being silently added to the plaintext email?

I've already tried asking the same thing at
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windowslive/forum/mail-email/outlookcom-adds-extra-characters-in-plain-text/04c3ec7f-0c26-42d9-94f5-85a71536fe54?page=1

With hilarious/sad-it-will-make-you-cry results as the replies appear to be from automated bots that appear to reply with stock answers based on keywords in my posts.